# texto reduciendo 1 carácter cada vez

Tags: delphi

¿Como crear un algoritmo en **delphi** para mostrar un texto reduciendo 1 carácter cada vez, usando `function`?

```
  ejem:
  hola mundo
  hola mund
  hola mun
  hola mu
  hola m
  hola 
  hol
  ho
  h
```

Answer (score 0):

Acá escribí un sencillo ejemplo utilizando una función, que a su vez se basa en una llamada a las funciones estándar `copy` y `length` para remover el último caracter de la cadena.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

function QuitarUltimaLetra(const S: string): string;
  begin
    Result := Copy(S, 1, Length(S) - 1);
  end;

var
  S : string;
begin
  S := 'Hola mundo';
  while S <> '' do
  begin
    Writeln(S);
    S := QuitarUltimaLetra(S);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Su salida es:

[image: Salida del programa]

Answer (score -1):

No se de delphi pero el algoritmo es simple:

```
string str = "Hola mundo"; // el string o equivalente

/* un ciclo con dos contadores, uno para imprimir el texto y otro para reducir el string en uno cada vez.*/

for(int i = 0, reduce = str.length(); i < str.length(); i++, reduce--)
{
    /* un ciclo que imprime los caracteres desde 0 hasta el tamaño del string menos la cantidad que se haya reducido hasta el momento*/

    for(int j = 0; j < reduce; j++)
    {
        print str[j]; // imprime caracter
    }
    print "\n"; //imprime nueva linea
}
```